# How do I response / return JSON from Python REST API

Tags: python, mysql, json, rest, python-3.x

I Have Python REST Api that will receive request from client, send to mysql stored proc then return / response back to client as JSON.

I have MySQL stored proc return something like below:

```
| val | type | status |
|-----|------|--------|
|  90 |    1 |      a |
```

then I catch that back again in Python and parse it using dict as follow:

```
class DateTimeEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, datetime):
            return o.isoformat()

        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, o)
##########################################################################################
try:
    with self.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor) as cursor:
        cursor.callproc('mysproc',[param])
        self.connection.commit()
        result = json.dumps(cursor.fetchone(), cls=DateTimeEncoder)
except:
    #bla...
finally:
    #bla...

return ???
```

so, with code above, if I do `return result` it will giving me: `"{\"val\": 90, \"type\": 1, \"status\": \"a\"}"`

how do I parse (gracefully) the result so it will be able to return JSON properly as if I hardcode Python return value like below:

```
return {'val': 90, 'type': 1, 'status': 'a'}
```

if i do return code above, it'll return me a proper JSON format which my client will be able to handle properly.

Thanks

Comment: @tinySandy thanks for your reply, and nope, it not work, i just tried that, but it still giving me same result as 'return result'

Comment: it seems like you are double-encoding it and it adds escaping chars

Comment: @tinySandy, could be, because i have DateTimeEncoder which i have to do that to process my datetime return from MySQL (i update my question FYR), so if that the case, how do i solve this? because i can't remove DateTimeEncoder

Comment: what about returning json.loads(result) ?

Comment: right,,, that works and i got the idea, but seems like not a proper way to do it, coz seems like it does double encode then decode back.